# Permission denied with podman and mounted volumes on MacOS

Tags: podman

I use podman 4.6.1 under macOS Ventura 13.5 as a replacement for docker. It's configured in rootless mode.

I run the following command to start a container to process a local file:

```bash
podman run --rm --name foo -v "$PWD:/code" $DOCKER_IMAGE
```

Inside the container i have a script that should process the file but it finishes with a `Permission Denied` message when it tries to edit the local file. The script just replace a specific information. The message output is:

```bash
sed: couldn't open temporary file ./sed66yRrG: Permission denied
```

From the container, if I run the `id` command i get:

```bash
➜  path id
uid=1001(image-user) gid=1001(image-user) groups=1001(image-user)
```

But the file owner is the `root` user:

```bash
➜  path ls -lhtra
-rw-r--r--. 1 root          nobody        2.0K Aug 21 14:47 properties.ini
```

And locally it is my user:

```bash
❯ ls -lhtra
-rw-r--r--@  1 myuser  mygroup   2.0K Aug 21 11:47 properties.ini
```

I have tried to run the `podman` command with the `--userns=keep-id`. Podman create a new user called `core` that maps the `uid` to my local user, but the `Permission denied` still happens:

```bash
podman run --rm --name foo --userns=keep-id -v "$PWD:/code" $DOCKER_IMAGE
```

```bash
➜  path ls -lhtra
-rw-r--r--. 1 core          nobody        2.0K Aug 21 14:47 properties.ini
```

```bash
sed: couldn't open temporary file ./sed77hAfO: Permission denied
```

The same container running with docker, works just fine. The file inside the container have the `image-user` as the owner and is writable.

Comment: What about adding the user that needs access to the `mygroup` group? It has it's drawbacks, but it might be sufficient for a dev machine.

Comment: Just a guess, try `--userns keep-id:uid=1001,gid=1001`

Comment: I tried to `sudo su -` and `chown -R image-user:image-group code` but even this didn't work on the podman container. I just went back to docker for my task. Out of curiosity, docker also starts with `root:nobody` permissions, but i'm able to `sudo su -` and `chown -R image-user:image-group code` and everything worked just fine.